# How to make this input so when more than 1 text is added to it then it adds more text in p2

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, input

I am trying to make a time management website and I am struggling. I want to have it so when you add a task in the input and press the "add task" button that it adds it to p2 above it and makes it so the user is able to add more than one task. I am also trying to make it have priority levels. This way you can click a button next to your newly added task and change the colors from red, green, and orange. If you could also add this it would be great, however, if you don't want to I completely understand. I would really appreciate the help :)

```html
<html>
    
 <style>
     
.title {
    
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 45px;
    color: #b72121;
    
}
     
    </style>
<header>
<title>ManageMe</title>
</header>
<body>
<div>
<h1 class= "title"> ManageMe </h1>
    <font face = "Times New Roman" size = "7">Next 7 Day Outlook</font><br />
    <div> 
        <h2> Today <span class= "june13">June 13</span></h2> 
        <div class="line1">
            <div> <br>
                <div id= "bonus">
                    <p id= "p1"> </p>
                     <p id= "p2"> </p>
                     <p id= "p3"> </p>
                     <p id= "p4"> </p>
                </div>
  <input id= "first" type="text" name="firstname" value="Enter Task Here">
  <br>  
                <div>
                <button class="button" onclick ="addtask()"> Add Task </button>
                    
                 <div id="div">
                     
                     <div> 
        <h2 class= "tom"> Tomorrow <span class= "june14">June 14</span></h2> 
        <div class="line2"> 
                         </div>
                     </div>
 </div>
                    <div>
                    </div>
                    
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
         <style>
     
.title {
    
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 45px;
    color: #b72121;
    
}
             
 .june13 {
     
     
     font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
     font-size: 14px;
     color: #989da5;   
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
 } 
             
.line1 {
    
    width: 30%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #666;
    opacity: 0.50;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    
             }   
    
.button {
  
  font-size: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none; 
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
  height: 25px;
    width: 70px;
}
.button:hover {
    background-color: #3e8e41
    }

    .button:active {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}

             input {
              
                 margin-bottom: 10px;
                 
             }
             
.june14 {
     
     
     font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
     font-size: 14px;
     color: #989da5;   
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
 } 
             
.line2 {
    
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #666;
    opacity: 10.300;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    
             }   
             
         .tom {
             
             color: #111111;
             
             }
    
    
             
    </style>

</div>
    
    <script>
        
        
     function addtask() {
        
       var first = document.getElementById("first").value;
       document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = first;
         
      
         }
        
         function addtask1() {
        
       var first = document.getElementById("first").value;
       document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = first;
         
      
         }
        
       
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see when you add a second task it changes the first one. This is not what I want. I just want it to add another one underneath the first one. I have also run into the problem where the text that says "tomorrow" and "june 14" have a lighter opacity. However, I can't figure out why they are different colors than the top ones. I just don't know. 
thanks for any help. I am new to coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `addtask()` is always adding value to the `p1` instead you need to target the `bonus` div and then append `p`s into it.

addtask method -

```
function addtask() {
  var first = document.getElementById("first").value;
  document.getElementById("bonus").innerHTML += "<p>"+first+"</p>";
}
```

Working Example -

```html
<html>
    
 <style>
     
.title {
    
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 45px;
    color: #b72121;
    
}
     
    </style>
<header>
<title>ManageMe</title>
</header>
<body>
<div>
<h1 class= "title"> ManageMe </h1>
    <font face = "Times New Roman" size = "7">Next 7 Day Outlook</font><br />
    <div> 
        <h2> Today <span class= "june13">June 13</span></h2> 
        <div class="line1">
            <div> <br>
                <div id= "bonus">
                    
                </div>
  <input id= "first" type="text" name="firstname" value="Enter Task Here">
  <br>  
                <div>
                <button class="button" onclick ="addtask()"> Add Task </button>
                    
                 <div id="div">
                     
                     <div> 
        <h2 class= "tom"> Tomorrow <span class= "june14">June 14</span></h2> 
        <div class="line2"> 
                         </div>
                     </div>
 </div>
                    <div>
                    </div>
                    
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
         <style>
     
.title {
    
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 45px;
    color: #b72121;
    
}
             
 .june13 {
     
     
     font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
     font-size: 14px;
     color: #989da5;   
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
 } 
             
.line1 {
    
    width: 30%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #666;
    opacity: 0.50;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    
             }   
    
.button {
  
  font-size: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none; 
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
  height: 25px;
    width: 70px;
}
.button:hover {
    background-color: #3e8e41
    }

    .button:active {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}

             input {
              
                 margin-bottom: 10px;
                 
             }
             
.june14 {
     
     
     font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
     font-size: 14px;
     color: #989da5;   
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
 } 
             
.line2 {
    
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #666;
    opacity: 10.300;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    
             }   
             
         .tom {
             
             color: #111111;
             
             }
    
    
             
    </style>

</div>
    
    <script>
        
        
     function addtask() {
        
       var first = document.getElementById("first").value;
       document.getElementById("bonus").innerHTML += "<p>"+first+"</p>";
         
      
         }
        
         function addtask1() {
        
       var first = document.getElementById("first").value;
       document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = first;
         
      
         }
        
       
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

For Opacity issue, you have opacity applied at `line1` which is containing your inner `h2` making it blur.

Comment: ohh thank you sooooooooooooo much, however, I am still confused by the blur you explained. How would I fix it?